# return an observable pipe in a function versus assign to a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, class, rxjs

I have a functional code snippet that uses the Angular service to create an Observable pipeline. The code employs the mergeMap, filter, map, and shareReplay(1) operators to handle user authentication and retrieve the onboarding status from a user profile. The pipeline is intended to be reused to observe changes in the onboarding status efficiently.

When I encapsulate this logic in a function and return the resulting Observable or assign it to a class property, I observe different behaviors. When I return the Observable from the function, the entire chain within the pipe executes on each subscription. On the other hand, if I assign the Observable to a class property, the shareReplay(1) operator works as expected, and the entire chain executes only once.

I am perplexed by this discrepancy and suspect it may be related to the creation of new instances. Could you help me understand why the behavior differs between returning the Observable from a function and assigning it to a class property? How can I achieve consistent behavior with the shareReplay(1) operator in both scenarios?

```
user$ = user(this.auth).pipe(shareReplay(1));

getStatus(): Observable<> {
 return this.angularService.user$.pipe(
            mergeMap(user => {
                console.log('Onboarding merge map');
                return this.angularService.getUserProfile(user?.uid || "").pipe(
                    filter(({ profile, user }) => {
                        console.log('Filter: ', profile['onboarding'])
                        return profile && profile['onboarding'];
                    }),
                    map(d => d.profile['onboarding'])
                )
            }),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
}
```

```
user$ = user(this.auth).pipe(shareReplay(1));

readonly onboardingStatus$: Observable<> = this.angularService.user$.pipe(
            mergeMap(user => {
                console.log('Onboarding merge map');
                return this.angularService.getUserProfile(user?.uid || "").pipe(
                    filter(({ profile, user }) => {
                        console.log('Filter: ', profile['onboarding'])
                        return profile && profile['onboarding'];
                    }),
                    map(d => d.profile['onboarding'])
                )
            }),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
```

UPDATE:
Adding function that can cause calling 'new' when you return, will give update if changing it into variable could change original function behavior:

```
getUserProfile(uid: string): Observable<{ profile: DocumentData, user: User }> {
        return documentSnapshot(doc(this.firestore, "users", uid)).pipe(
            tap((val) => console.log(`userProfile document snapshot executed`, val)),
            mergeMap((document) => (of({ profile: document.data(), user } as any))),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a function like this

```
function retObs() {
   return of('something')
}
```

any time you invoke such function, you get a new Observable instance. Hence if you have something like this

```
function retObs() {
   return of('something'),pipe(share(1))
}
const sub1 = retObs().subscribe()
const sub2 = retObs().subscribe()
```

each subscription subscribes to a different Observable chain, hence `shareReplay(1)` does not have any effect on these subscription.

On the contrary, if you save the Observable instance returned by `retObs()` in a variable, then all subscriptions to the Observable held by the variable share the same Observable chain, hence you see the effects of `shareReplay(1)` you would expect.

```
const var = retObs()
const sub1 = var.subscribe()
const sub2 = var.subscribe()
```

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-j39tl6?file=index.ts) shows this concept in action.

Comment: I asked chatGPT and it mentioned that, so great a human can confirm. Also it mentioned defer function from RxJS, I have not tried it yet, but can it help to make one invocation of new? Is there other options to make it 'singleton' like, for instance, use static(might not help because function depends on class variables)  ? I see the other option would be internal variable and return it...

Comment: So in my code it looks like getUserProfile does that new operator?

Comment: A new Observable is created any time you execute `this.angularService.user$.pipe(....)`. It is the same thing as calling `slice` on an array, it returns a new array. Any time you call `getStatus()` you create a new instance of Observable. In the process of creating such instance you also call `getUserProfile`, but I would say that this is a detail, not the root cause.